# Powershell - using wildcards to search for filename

Tags: variables, powershell, wildcard, get-childitem

I am trying to make a PowerShell script that will search a folder for a filename that contains a certain file-mask.  All files in the folder will have format like `*yyyyMd*.txt`.

I have made a script:

```powershell
[String]$date = $(get-date -format yyyyMd)
$date1 = $date.ToString
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\pelam\Desktop\DOM | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*$date1*'}
```

But this does not seem to work..

Can anyone help?  It seems the problem is that the date variable is not correct because when I hard code something like below, it works:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\pelam\Desktop\DOM | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*20141013*'}
```

Comment: The single quotes are causing it to try to match the liter string '$date1'.  Use double quotes to enable variable expansion in the string.

Comment: Or better yet, don't quote a variable reference that is already a string e.g. `... | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $date1}`  :-)

Comment: Thanks guys!  It worked!  I had ot use double quotes instead of single..

Comment: Use single quotes inside of double quotes ("'*$date1*'") if $date1 could contain embedded spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simplify this by just using regex with the `-match` operator:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\pelam\Desktop\DOM | Where-Object {$_ -match (Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd)}
```

And if you are on V3 or higher, you can further simplify to:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\pelam\Desktop\DOM | Where Name -match (Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd)
```

Comment: This seems like it could work.  But the file name will be something like 'medical20141014-12345.txt'.  So I need it to get ?yyyyMd?.  So that it can find any files that contain the current date.  Is that doable with -match?

Comment: OK, I'm being an idiot today.  The updated answer will work and the nature of `-match` and the resulting regex pattern, will find the date string anywhere in the filename.