# Powershell - Using wildcards in path to search for filename in a specific subfolder

Tags: powershell, wildcard, get-childitem

Extension of the post [Powershell - using wildcards to search for filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365486/powershell-using-wildcards-to-search-for-filename)

Hi There!

Let's assume we have this files and folders configuration:

```
C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\level03.txt
C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\level03.yml
C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\FolderLevel04\level04.txt
C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\FolderLevel04\level04.yml
C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\FolderLevel04\Contract\contract.txt
C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\FolderLevel04\Contract\contract.yml
```

We can retrieve the contract.yml file if we have the correct folder tree structure in the "Path" argument:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\FolderLevel01\FolderLevel02\FolderLevel03\FolderLevel04\Contract\" -Include "*.yml" -Recurse
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\FolderLevel01\*\*\*\Contract\" -Include "*.yml" -Recurse
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\FolderLevel01\*\*\*\Contract\*.yml"
```

But how to retrieve the "Contract\*.yml" if

- you don't know in advance the folder tree
- the file name is unkwnown (except yml extension)
  The only info you have is
- the file is in a specific folder (i.e. Contract)
- the file as a secific extensioin (i.e. *.yml)

A command such as the following does not work:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\FolderLevel01\" -Include "Contract\*.yml" -Recurse
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:

```
$folder=(Get-ChildItem .\FolderLevel01\\Contract -Recurse)
$file=(Get-ChildItem ($folder.FullName + '\*.yml'))
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I did also in 2 steps, but I was looking for perhaps an impossible shortest command :-)